# Getting a specific instance of a Tkinter label created using a FOR LOOP

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a complete novice to programming and I have also never posted on this forum before so I apologise in advance if my question if not clear or I am not using the correct terminology but I would really appreciate some assistance.

I have created a simple pilot log book program using Python 3.7.0 and Tkinter.
Screenshot with some personal information redacted:
[Log book screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNWv1.png)

I have created and packed the heading frame using explicit statements (example code shown below).

Then next I have a "data" frame where I loop through a dictionary.  For each item in the dictionary I pack a new row of data to the dataframe (example code shown below).

The issue I have is that I want to call a callback function when I click on a row in the data frame (to allow editing of that row).  However I can only seem to get the last item in the dictionary that was packed into the frame regardless of which row I click on.

Is there any way to call the specific instance of the frame that was packed rather than the final frame?

Example explicit heading frame code:

```
        # Heading Frame:
        self.heading_year_frame = tk.Frame(self.headingframe)
        self.heading_year_entry = tk.Label(self.heading_year_frame, width=self.entrywidth, text="YEAR", anchor='sw', font = self.fontsize, bd = 1, relief = "flat")
        self.heading_year_entry.pack(side='left', fill='y')
        heading_frames.append(self.heading_year_frame)
...
        self.heading_details_frame = tk.Frame(self.headingframe)
        self.heading_details_entry = tk.Label(self.heading_details_frame, width=self.bigentrywidth*2, text="DETAILS", anchor='sw', font = self.fontsize, bd = 1, relief = "flat")
        self.heading_details_entry.pack(side='left', fill='y')
        heading_frames.append(self.heading_details_frame)
 
...
        # Pack the heading frames
        for f in heading_frames:
            f.pack(side='left', fill='both')
```

Example frames generated using FOR LOOP and dictionary:

```
    def pack_entry(self):
        self.dataframe_regen = tk.Frame(self.dataframe)
        self.dataframe_regen.pack(side='top', fill='both')
        for i in self.flight_list[self.m:self.n]:
            self.i = self.flight_data[i]
            self.entry_year = (self.flight_data[i]["year"])
.....
            self.entry_details = (self.flight_data[i]["details"])
.....
            self.entry_year_frame = tk.Frame(self.subdataframe)
            self.entry_year_entry = tk.Label(self.entry_year_frame, width=self.entrywidth, text= self.entry_year, font = self.fontsize, anchor = 'w', bd =1, relief = 'flat')
            self.entry_year_entry.pack(side='left', fill = 'both', expand = True)
            self.sub_data_frames.append(self.entry_year_frame)
....
            self.entry_details_frame = tk.Frame(self.subdataframe)
            self.entry_details_entry = tk.Label(self.entry_details_frame, width=self.bigentrywidth*2, text= self.entry_details, font = self.fontsize, anchor = 'w', bd = 1, relief = "flat", cursor = "hand2")
            self.entry_details_entry.pack(side='left', fill='x')
            self.entry_details_entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:self.popup_showinfo())
            self.sub_data_frames.append(self.entry_details_frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of strategies for doing this, but it kind of depends on how you want to access, make changes to the row.

In any of the cases below, though, your callback must somehow be aware of which row it's changing. A couple things you can do

1. use a lambda just as you did in the label and pass the row identifying information (whatever it is) into the inner function.
2. use `functools.partial` so that you can write one function and create partials for each row, e.g.

```
def edit_row(event, row_identifying_object=None):
    # use row_identifying_object to find the correct row or make any 
    # changes you want to the row_identifying_object directly

for irow in range(n_rows):
    # row_obj = some object, number, string to identify row
    lbl = tk.Label()
    # this will create a new partial object that will call your 
    # function above with the row_identifying_object pre-defined 
    # to whatever row_obj is and bind it to the callback
    lbl.bind('<button-1>', functools.partial(edit_row, row_identifying_object = row_obj))
```

As for what the `row_obj` is, it could be

-an identifier pointing to some other structure that keeps track of your rows. This might be an ugly solution since the program now needs to keep track and link this id to the however the row contents are managed.

-probably the more common one I've see is to define a "row" object itself that keeps track of its identities or all its children. This object could be a `tk.Frame` itself, e.g.

```
class Row():
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(*args, **kwargs)
        # instantiate your elements in each row here

    def getter(self, element_id):
        # retrieve elements in row by some id

    def setter(self, element_id, *args, **kwargs):
        # make changes to elements in the row
```

A lot of answers I've seen and I've actually used have `Row` inherit from `tk.Frame`, but then you have to be careful about making sure you handle the circular references appropriately. Python has become pretty robust to memory leaks from circular references, but there are still a lot of warnings around about creating them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I will digest what you have suggested, try to implement it then report back.